# how to persistently store json data using jquery after browser refresh

Tags: jquery, html, json, facebook, web

Background: I am trying to access Facebook shares via http://graph.facebook.com/url to display share count.

Problem: The values after refresh just sets to zero.

here is the code I am using:

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/'+url,function(data) {
$("#facebook_shares").text(data.shares || 0);
fval = (data.shares || 0);
});
```

fval is then used for display and charting purposes. 
While display as a number is fine but in the charts it just sets itself as zero after refresh.